# Android import apk file problem

Tags: android, google-play, apk, keystore

I have created a `keystore` and created a `apk` file for `version` 1.0 of the app with the same keystore. But after that due to some prob, my pc is crashed and no more usable. But I have the keystore file using which I have developed the apk for version 1.0. Now I want to release version 2.0 of the same app. I used the same code-base and build the `apk` using the same `keystore` file. I tried to upload it to the Android Market, but it rejected the `apk` file. What is reason behind it? What is solution for the problem?

Comment: what is the error message you get? Have you increased the versionCode in the manifest (not the versionName...)?

Comment: It is giving "The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version." as error msg. We have changed the version code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only the keystore is important, but the same key should be used to sign the apk.

Comment: When you extract signed package with IDE it should ask for the keystore firstly and then for the key. Choose the same you key you have used first time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have tried to upload the 'debug'-apk instead of the release-apk. The only other explanation is that you have signed it with a different keystore file - or with a different key from the same keystore. Check your file paths.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to place the keystore file in the same filepath where it is created?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have used the **same password(key) and  keystore** that was created for the earlier version 1.0.

Check your manifest file too that have you **modified the version name and version code**.

See this part of your manifest file:

```
  android:versionCode="2"    // New version code
  android:versionName="1.1"   // New version name
```

Hope this will solve your issue.